# The page isn't redirecting properly when I logout

Tags: php, mysql, session, redirect

```
<?php
// Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
include 'connection.php';

// session_start();

$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];
// SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User

$ses_sql=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM auth where email='$user_check'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);

$login_session =$row['email'];
$username =$row['name'];
$created_at =$row['created_at'];
$city =$row['city'];
$phone =$row['phone'];
$profile_photo =$row['photo'];

if(!isset($login_session)){
    mysqli_close($conn); // Closing Connection
    header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
}
?>
```

I am commenting out the `session_start()` because I'm already starting the  session in another php file that is included.

I can't understand why the the page isn't redirecting properly to the `index.php` file.

Comment: errr... why is this commented out `// session_start();`? Your whole code depends on it *NOT being commented out*. Also make sure you're not outputting before header.

Comment: check if you are even going to the if condition. I think that your $login_session will always be set because you are declaring it.

Comment: is your `index.php` is in the same directory/folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment your session start

```
session_start();
```

Also make sure there is no html before you start your session

Answer (score 0):

The `header()` function needs for Location: a absolute path, e.g. http://example.org.

> Note:
>   HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself: [...] [SOURCE][1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

As of this your header function are not correct on most servers. I have one server who accepts relative URIs and one which needs absolute URIs for example.

You should use `exit()` after `header` to supress further execution of the script too.

Comment: it SHOULD be an absolute path, but most browsers will accept a relative one and "just work".

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you have a `include` in your code and you said the session_start() is there. Just make sure that `include` don't have any output in it. And session_start is actually the first thing called there.

More info:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php